# Android : No Activity found to handle Intent Error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        String item = items.get(position);
        viewHolder.setItem(item);
        viewHolder.imageGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = items.get(position);
                Log.d("GA onClick", "" + url);

                if (url.contains("youtu")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and Error message :

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= https://youtu.be/VJAPZ9cIbs0 }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4506)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4464)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4825)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4793)
        at org.thk.mymovie.gallery.GalleryAdapter$1.onClick(GalleryAdapter.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6313)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24933)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6722)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

I saw more stack overflow questions about this problem.
but, in my case some links are work well.
So, I dont know what the problem is.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: `No Activity found to handle Intent` means that there is no application installed on the phone, which could `ACTION_VIEW` your provided Url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Avoid App crash when there's no Activity to handle an Intent by  surrounding your Intent with a Try-Catch, Catching ActivityNotFoundException and have it do something else when there's no activity to open the intent instead of crashing the app:

```
          if (url.contains("youtu")) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                     //Then Do something here
                     //Maybe a Toast to tell User they don't have an Activity that 
                     //can     
                     //open that intent or open it via Browser
                }
            }
```

This way, You keep your app from crashing and you retain your users. Also, you handle a scenario where there's no activity to open an Intent

Comment: @TaeHoom Kim, if this solves the problem for you, Kindly accept the answer and mark as correct so others who fall into this can easily find a solution